Create/Edit Commands for Finance Agreements that involve document upload
I'm working on commands for creating and updating FinanceAgreement records in a .NET application. The goal is to streamline and clean up the document-handling logic.
Problem Description:
In our current implementation, we have a CreateFinanceAgreementCommandHandler and an UpdateFinanceAgreementCommandHandler. These handle creation and update logic for a FinanceAgreement, respectively. However, there are some concerns about how documents are handled and mapped:

Create Finance Agreement:

The requirement is that documents should not be uploaded or processed during creation.
The AutoMapper profile already ignores the Documents property in the mapping, and no manual mapping is performed for Documents in the CreateFinanceAgreementCommandHandler.
While this is correct behavior, the omission is implicit and not obvious from the design.


Update Finance Agreement:

During an update, documents should be processed to allow for additions, modifications, or deletions.
In the UpdateFinanceAgreementCommandHandler, this is handled manually through a .Select() projection after fetching the existing entity from the database. The AutoMapper profile explicitly ignores the Documents property, and then we're manually mapping it, which feels kinda wrong.


DTO Design:

For Create, the DTOs should not include Id fields for documents, as the database generates these IDs.
For Update, Id fields are required to correctly match existing documents to their updates or removals.



I would like to get a review on this approach as it feels a bit odd to me. Personally, I think having a centralized IFormFile upload endpoint is a good idea. For instance, uploading the files immediately upon selection and then using their documentUrl reference in the form submission makes it faster and feel a bit more modular.
Additionally, the use of a background service with a cron job to remove unused documents (those not linked to any entity) ensures proper cleanup. In fact, this approach seems quite similar to how ChatGPT's file upload system works.
However, I feel there is room for simplification. Any suggestions on how to streamline this further?
The manual mapping should be removed because it currently deletes the existing document references and creates new ones. This approach is problematic for maintaining the auditable properties UpdatedAt and UpdatedBy, as these are not preserved with the current implementation.
public sealed record CreateFinanceAgreementCommand : IRequest<Result<Guid>>
{
    public required FinanceAgreementDto FinanceAgreement { get; init; }
}

public sealed class CreateFinanceAgreementCommandHandler(AppDbContext dbContext, IMapper mapper) : IRequestHandler<CreateFinanceAgreementCommand, Result<Guid>>
{
    public async Task<Result<Guid>> Handle(CreateFinanceAgreementCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var financeAgreement = mapper.Map<FinanceAgreement>(request.FinanceAgreement);
        dbContext.FinanceAgreements.Add(financeAgreement);
        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

        var financeAgreementLegalEntities = request.FinanceAgreement.FinanceAgreementLegalEntities
            .Select(le => new FinanceAgreementLegalEntity
            {
                FinanceAgreementId = financeAgreement.Id,
                LegalEntityId = le.LegalEntityId,
                RoleType = le.RoleType,
                Notes = le.Notes
            });

        dbContext.Set<FinanceAgreementLegalEntity>().AddRange(financeAgreementLegalEntities);

        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

        return financeAgreement.Id;
    }
}

public sealed class UpdateFinanceAgreementCommand : IRequest<Result<Unit>>
{
    public required Guid Id { get; init; }
    public required FinanceAgreementUpdateDto FinanceAgreement { get; init; }
}

public sealed class UpdateFinanceAgreementCommandHandler(AppDbContext dbContext, IMapper mapper) : IRequestHandler<UpdateFinanceAgreementCommand, Result<Unit>>
{
    public async Task<Result<Unit>> Handle(UpdateFinanceAgreementCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var financeAgreement = await dbContext.FinanceAgreements
            .Include(x => x.FinanceAgreementLegalEntities)
            .Include(x => x.Documents)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == request.Id, cancellationToken);

        if (financeAgreement == null)
        {
            return new Result<Unit>(new NotFoundException(request.Id.ToString(), nameof(Deal)));
        }

        mapper.Map(request.FinanceAgreement, financeAgreement);

        dbContext.RemoveRange(financeAgreement.FinanceAgreementLegalEntities);

        var newFinanceAgreementLegalEntities = request.FinanceAgreement.FinanceAgreementLegalEntities
            .Select(x => new FinanceAgreementLegalEntity
            {
                FinanceAgreementId = financeAgreement.Id,
                LegalEntityId = x.LegalEntityId,
                RoleType = x.RoleType,
                Notes = x.Notes
            });
        dbContext.Set<FinanceAgreementLegalEntity>().AddRange(newFinanceAgreementLegalEntities);

        dbContext.RemoveRange(financeAgreement.Documents);

        var newDocuments = request.FinanceAgreement.Documents
            .Select(x => new FinanceAgreementDocument
            {
                FileType = x.FileType,
                DocumentType = x.DocumentType,
                Name = x.Name,
                Description = x.Description,
                Url = x.Url,
                DocumentCategory = x.DocumentCategory.ToString(),
                FinanceAgreementId = financeAgreement.Id
            });
        dbContext.Set<FinanceAgreementDocument>().AddRange(newDocuments);

        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

        return Unit.Value;
    }
}

public class FinanceAgreementConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<FinanceAgreement>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<FinanceAgreement> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(nameof(FinanceAgreement), SchemaNames.FinanceAgreements);

        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder.Property(x => x.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        builder.Property(x => x.AgreementType).HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(x => x.AgreementName).HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(x => x.FacilityType).HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired(false);

        builder.Property(x => x.AgreementStatus).HasMaxLength(20).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(x => x.StartDate).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(x => x.MaturityDate).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(x => x.Currency).HasMaxLength(3).IsRequired();

        builder.Property(x => x.TotalAgreementAmount).HasPrecision(18, 2).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(x => x.ExpectedRepaymentAmount).HasPrecision(18, 2).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(x => x.ProfitPercentage).HasPrecision(5, 2).IsRequired(false);
        builder.Property(x => x.ProfitAmount).HasPrecision(18, 2).IsRequired(false);
        builder.Property(x => x.ExpectedRepaymentDate).IsRequired();

        builder.Property(x => x.InterestRate).HasPrecision(5, 2).IsRequired(false);
        builder.Property(x => x.InterestRateType).HasConversion<string>().HasMaxLength(20).IsRequired(false);
        builder.Property(x => x.Margin).HasPrecision(5, 2).IsRequired(false);
        builder.Property(x => x.BenchmarkRateType).HasMaxLength(20).IsRequired(false);
        builder.Property(x => x.BenchmarkRate).HasPrecision(5, 2).IsRequired(false);
        builder.Property(x => x.InterestCalculationMethod).HasConversion<string>().HasMaxLength(20).IsRequired(false);
        builder.Property(x => x.RepaymentMethod).HasConversion<string>().HasMaxLength(20).IsRequired(false);
        builder.Property(x => x.RepaymentFrequency).HasConversion<string>().HasMaxLength(20).IsRequired(false);

        builder.Property(x => x.GracePeriod).IsRequired(false);
        builder.Property(x => x.DrawdownLimit).HasPrecision(18, 2).IsRequired(false);
        builder.Property(x => x.IsReinvested).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(x => x.CollateralValue).HasPrecision(18, 2).IsRequired(false);
        builder.Property(x => x.PreviousDealId).IsRequired(false);
        builder.Property(x => x.DealId).IsRequired(false);

        builder
            .HasMany(d => d.LegalEntities)
            .WithMany()
            .UsingEntity<FinanceAgreementLegalEntity>(
                j =>
                {
                    j.ToTable(nameof(FinanceAgreementLegalEntity), SchemaNames.FinanceAgreements);

                    j.Property(dl => dl.RoleType).HasConversion<string>().HasMaxLength(20).IsRequired();
                    j.Property(dl => dl.Notes).HasConversion<string>().HasMaxLength(500).IsRequired();

                    j.HasOne<LegalEntity>()
                        .WithMany()
                        .HasForeignKey(dl => dl.LegalEntityId)
                        .HasPrincipalKey(l => l.Id);

                    j.HasOne<FinanceAgreement>()
                        .WithMany(d => d.FinanceAgreementLegalEntities)
                        .HasForeignKey(dl => dl.FinanceAgreementId)
                        .HasPrincipalKey(d => d.Id);
                });

        builder
            .HasMany(d => d.Transactions)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.FinanceAgreementId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

        builder
            .HasMany(d => d.Documents)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.FinanceAgreementId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
    }
}

public class FinanceAgreement : BaseAuditableEntity
{
    public AgreementType AgreementType { get; set; }
    public required string AgreementName { get; set; }
    public FacilityType? FacilityType { get; set; }
    public AgreementStatus AgreementStatus { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime MaturityDate { get; set; }
    public required string Currency { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalAgreementAmount { get; set; }
    public decimal ExpectedRepaymentAmount { get; set; }
    public decimal? ProfitPercentage { get; set; }
    public decimal? ProfitAmount { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpectedRepaymentDate { get; set; }
    public decimal? InterestRate { get; set; }
    public InterestRateType? InterestRateType { get; set; }
    public decimal? Margin { get; set; }
    public BenchmarkRateType? BenchmarkRateType { get; set; }
    public decimal? BenchmarkRate { get; set; }
    public InterestCalculationMethod? InterestCalculationMethod { get; set; }
    public RepaymentMethod? RepaymentMethod { get; set; }
    public RepaymentFrequency? RepaymentFrequency { get; set; }
    public int? GracePeriod { get; set; }
    public decimal? DrawdownLimit { get; set; }
    public bool IsReinvested { get; set; }
    public decimal? CollateralValue { get; set; }
    public Guid? PreviousDealId { get; set; }
    public Guid? DealId { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<LegalEntity> LegalEntities { get; set; } = new List<LegalEntity>();
    public ICollection<FinanceAgreementLegalEntity> FinanceAgreementLegalEntities { get; set; } = new List<FinanceAgreementLegalEntity>();
    public ICollection<FinanceAgreementTransaction> Transactions { get; set; } = new List<FinanceAgreementTransaction>();
    public ICollection<FinanceAgreementDocument> Documents { get; set; } = new List<FinanceAgreementDocument>();
}

public record FinanceAgreementDto
{
    public AgreementType AgreementType { get; init; }
    public required string AgreementName { get; init; }
    public FacilityType? FacilityType { get; init; }
    public AgreementStatus AgreementStatus { get; init; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; init; }
    public DateTime MaturityDate { get; init; }
    public required string Currency { get; init; }
    public decimal TotalAgreementAmount { get; init; }
    public decimal ExpectedRepaymentAmount { get; init; }
    public decimal? ProfitPercentage { get; init; }
    public decimal? ProfitAmount { get; init; }
    public DateTime ExpectedRepaymentDate { get; init; }
    public decimal? InterestRate { get; init; }
    public InterestRateType? InterestRateType { get; init; }
    public decimal? Margin { get; init; }
    public BenchmarkRateType? BenchmarkRateType { get; init; }
    public decimal? BenchmarkRate { get; init; }
    public InterestCalculationMethod? InterestCalculationMethod { get; init; }
    public RepaymentMethod? RepaymentMethod { get; init; }
    public RepaymentFrequency? RepaymentFrequency { get; init; }
    public int? GracePeriod { get; init; }
    public decimal? DrawdownLimit { get; init; }
    public bool IsReinvested { get; init; }
    public decimal? CollateralValue { get; init; }
    public Guid? PreviousDealId { get; init; }
    public Guid? DealId { get; init; }
    public ICollection<FinanceAgreementLegalEntityDto> FinanceAgreementLegalEntities { get; init; } = new List<FinanceAgreementLegalEntityDto>();

    private class Mapping : Profile
    {
        public Mapping()
        {
            CreateMap<FinanceAgreement, FinanceAgreementDto>().ReverseMap();
            CreateMap<FinanceAgreementDto, FinanceAgreement>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.FinanceAgreementLegalEntities, opt => opt.Ignore());
        }
    }
}

public record FinanceAgreementUpdateDto
{
    public AgreementType AgreementType { get; init; }
    public required string AgreementName { get; init; }
    public FacilityType? FacilityType { get; init; }
    public AgreementStatus AgreementStatus { get; init; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; init; }
    public DateTime MaturityDate { get; init; }
    public required string Currency { get; init; }
    public decimal TotalAgreementAmount { get; init; }
    public decimal ExpectedRepaymentAmount { get; init; }
    public decimal? ProfitPercentage { get; init; }
    public decimal? ProfitAmount { get; init; }
    public DateTime ExpectedRepaymentDate { get; init; }
    public decimal? InterestRate { get; init; }
    public InterestRateType? InterestRateType { get; init; }
    public decimal? Margin { get; init; }
    public BenchmarkRateType? BenchmarkRateType { get; init; }
    public decimal? BenchmarkRate { get; init; }
    public InterestCalculationMethod? InterestCalculationMethod { get; init; }
    public RepaymentMethod? RepaymentMethod { get; init; }
    public RepaymentFrequency? RepaymentFrequency { get; init; }
    public int? GracePeriod { get; init; }
    public decimal? DrawdownLimit { get; init; }
    public bool IsReinvested { get; init; }
    public decimal? CollateralValue { get; init; }
    public Guid? PreviousDealId { get; init; }
    public Guid? DealId { get; init; }

    public ICollection<FinanceAgreementLegalEntityDto> FinanceAgreementLegalEntities { get; init; } = new List<FinanceAgreementLegalEntityDto>();
    public ICollection<FinanceAgreementDocumentDto> Documents { get; init; } = new List<FinanceAgreementDocumentDto>();

    private class Mapping : Profile
    {
        public Mapping()
        {
            CreateMap<FinanceAgreement, FinanceAgreementUpdateDto>().ReverseMap();
            CreateMap<FinanceAgreementUpdateDto, FinanceAgreement>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.FinanceAgreementLegalEntities, opt => opt.Ignore())
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Documents, opt => opt.Ignore());
        }
    }
}

public class FinanceAgreementLegalEntityDto
{
    public required Guid LegalEntityId { get; init; }
    public required string RoleType { get; init; }
    public required string Notes { get; init; }

    private class Mapping : Profile
    {
        public Mapping() =>
            CreateMap<FinanceAgreementLegalEntity, FinanceAgreementLegalEntityDto>()
                .ReverseMap();
    }
}

The document upload endpoint is separated as it's being reused by multiple forms:
public class DocumentUploadEndpoint : IEndpoint
{
    private const int MaxFileSizeInBytes = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10MB
    private static readonly string[] AllowedExtensions = [".pdf", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png"];

    public static void MapEndpoint(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(endpoints);

        endpoints.MapPost("/documents/upload",
                async (IFormFile file, IStorageService storageService) =>
                {
                    var validationResult = ValidateFile(file);
                    if (validationResult is not null)
                    {
                        return validationResult;
                    }

                    await using var fileStream = file.OpenReadStream();
                    var documentUrl = await storageService.UploadFileBlobAsync(fileStream, file.FileName);
                    return Results.Ok(new { DocumentUrl = documentUrl });
                })
            .Produces(StatusCodes.Status200OK)
            .ProducesProblem(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)
            .ProducesProblem(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)
            .DisableAntiforgery()
            .WithTags(nameof(Document))
            .RequireAuthorization();
    }

    private static IResult? ValidateFile(IFormFile file)
    {
        if (file.Length == 0)
        {
            return Results.BadRequest(new ProblemDetails
            {
                Title = "Validation Error",
                Detail = "No file was uploaded."
            });
        }

        if (file.Length > MaxFileSizeInBytes)
        {
            return Results.BadRequest(new ProblemDetails
            {
                Title = "Validation Error",
                Detail = "File size exceeds maximum limit of 10MB."
            });
        }

        var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLowerInvariant();
        if (!AllowedExtensions.Contains(fileExtension))
        {
            return Results.BadRequest(new ProblemDetails
            {
                Title = "Validation Error",
                Detail = "File type not supported. Allowed types: PDF, JPG, JPEG, PNG."
            });
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public interface IStorageService
{
    Task<string> UploadFileBlobAsync(Stream fileStream, string fileName, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);

    Task DeleteBlobByUrlAsync(string fileUrl, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
}

public class BlobStorageService(ILogger<BlobStorageService> logger, BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient, string containerName) : IStorageService
{
    public async Task<string> UploadFileBlobAsync(Stream fileStream, string fileName, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(fileStream);
        ArgumentException.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty(fileName);

        var blobFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") + Path.GetExtension(fileName);

        logger.LogInformation("Uploading to {FileName} in container {ContainerName} of account: {Account}...", blobFileName, containerName, blobServiceClient.AccountName);

        var containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
        await containerClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobFileName);

        var options = new BlobUploadOptions
        {
            HttpHeaders = new BlobHttpHeaders { ContentType = GetContentType(fileName) }
        };
        await blobClient.UploadAsync(fileStream, options, cancellationToken);

        return blobClient.Uri.ToString();
    }

    public async Task DeleteBlobByUrlAsync(string fileUrl, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        ArgumentException.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty(fileUrl);

        var blobUri = new Uri(fileUrl);
        var blobName = blobUri.Segments[^1];

        logger.LogInformation("Deleting blob: {BlobName} from container: {ContainerName}", blobName, containerName);

        var containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
        var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);

        await blobClient.DeleteIfExistsAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
    }

    private static string GetContentType(string filePath) =>
        Path.GetExtension(filePath).ToLowerInvariant() switch
        {
            ".pdf" => "application/pdf",
            ".jpg" or ".jpeg" => "image/jpeg",
            ".png" => "image/png",
            _ => "application/octet-stream"
        };
}


why do you handle navigations separately ? EF is smart enough to add or update related entities from the same entity. So, if you just add new records to FinanceAgreementLegalEntity or any other collection, EF should insert the records to the related table with one database call.

Small recommendation for implemention a file upload in a secure way:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-9.0#file-signature-validation
One of things mentioned in this best practice is to also check the files signature and not only the file extension in the filename. It's easy for malicious actors to change the file extension but upload a file of a type you dont support.

@ChrisKetilelaar Your comment is the start of a good answer. Would you be willing to expand it?

Personally, I look at this as a case of "sometimes business logic just is, and sometimes it's ugly." There's nothing glaringly obvious that is wrong here, it's just a matter of the domain having defined the answer as being one which isn't super pretty.
That said, there are a couple things that I would definitely do here to help.
First, and foremost, there are nearly duplicate blocks in the Create & Update methods that work on the FinanceAgreementLegalEntities, we should pull those out to a function that can operate on both the Create and Update logic.
private void UpsertFinanceAgreementLegalEntities(AppDbContext dbContext, FinanceAgreement financeAgreement, IEnumerable<FinanceAgreementLegalEntity> newLegalEntities)
{
    // ...
}

It's up to you whether you use LINQ for the upsert or not, but sometimes the best answer is to just throw a good old-fashioned foreach in and send it.
dbContext.RemoveRange(
    financeAgreement.FinanceAgreementLegalEntities.Where(
        ee => !newLegalEntities.Any(ne => ee.Id == ne.Id)));
foreach (var legalEntity in newLegalEntities)
{
    var existingEntity =
        financeAgreement.FinanceAgreementLegalEntities.SingleOrDefault(
            ee => ee.Id = legalEntity.Id);
    if (existingEntity != null)
    {
        // ... map entity, using your AutoMapper perhaps?
        // Additionally, check for audited changes for UpdatedAt/UpdatedBy
    }
    else
    {
        // ... create entity
    }
}

(And this brings up an interesting question: why are entities being manually updated in the DB Context? EF & EF Core both include change-tracking, is it disabled? If so, that's fine, but if not, I would recommend putting the objects together via navigation, rather than manually building the data tables.)
Next, I would do the same thing with Documents. This will help you enforce the UpdatedAt / UpdatedBy that you want to include, as you can do one of two things: add it to the auto-mapper configuration, or manually set it in the same foreach loop based on whether any properties change. In this case, I would build a custom .Equals method (in fact, I would create & implement IAuditComparer) and use that to determine if the requested FinanceAgreementDocument is changing from the current version.
public interface IAuditComparer<T>
    where T : class
{
    public bool Equals(T? a, T? b);
}

protected class FinanceAgreementDocumentUpdateAuditComparer : IAuditComparer<FinanceAgreementDocument>
{
    public bool Equals(FinanceAgreementDocument? fd1, FinanceAgreementDocument? fd2)
    {
        if (fd1 is null || fd2 is null)
            return false;

        return fd1.FileType == fd2.FileType
            && fd1.DocumentType == fd2.DocumentType
            && fd1.Name == fd2.Name
            && fd1.Description == fd2.Description
            && fd1.Url == fd2.Url
            && fd1.DocumentCategory == fd2.DocumentCategory
            && fd1.FinanceAgreementId == fd2.FinanceAgreementId;
    }
}

And as such, it's a simple matter of using the IAuditComparer:
public sealed class UpdateFinanceAgreementCommandHandler(AppDbContext dbContext, IMapper mapper) : IRequestHandler<UpdateFinanceAgreementCommand, Result<Unit>>
{
    public async Task<Result<Unit>> Handle(UpdateFinanceAgreementCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // ...
        UpsertDocuments(dbContext, financeAgreement, request.FinanceAgreement.FinanceAgreementDocuments);
        // ...
    }

    private void UpsertDocuments(AppDbContext dbContext, FinanceAgreement financeAgreement, IEnumerable<FinanceAgreementDocument> documents)
    {
        // ...
        var auditComparer = new FinanceAgreementDocumentUpdateAuditComparer();
        foreach (var newDocument in documents)
        {
            var existingDocument = financeAgreement.FinanceAgreementDocuments.SingleOrDefault(ee => ee.Id == newDocument.Id);
            if (existingDocument != null)
            {
                // Only update if we changed any audited fields
                if (!auditComparer.Equals(existingDocument, newDocument))
                {
                    // ... map with auto mapper perhaps

Likewise, for any audited objects, an IAuditComparer<T> can be built that can be injected with the standard DI templates likely in use.

In doing this (building an IAuditComparer<T>), for any Upsert-able item with an audit trail, there is a single concept that can be recycled amongst them to ensure that the proper fields are reviewed for auditing information, and that an update to a parent entity doesn't force an audit trail hit for the child. This makes the business logic much more clear as well.
If someone really wants to get clever, update the IAuditComparer to return a list of the changed fields instead, with an AuditAttribute for good measure, and move the generic constraint to the method to recycle the entire class:
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class AuditAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}

public class GenericAuditComparer
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Compare<T>(T? a, T? b)
        where T : class
    {
        if (a is null || b is null)
            return null;

        var auditProps = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(
            x => x.HasCustomAttribute(typeof(AuditAttribute));

        foreach (var auditProp in auditProps)
        {
            var attr = auditProp.GetCustomAttribute<AuditAttribute>();

            var valA = auditProp.GetValue(a);
            var valB = auditProp.GetValue(b);

            if (valA != null && valB != null
                && !valA.Equals(valB))
            {
                yield return attr?.Name ?? auditProp.Name;
            }
        }
    }
}

(I don't have a compiler in front of me so this might need tweaking to work effectively.)
The handy part about this approach is an object can be decorated with the AuditAttribute to choose what fields to compare to ensure that the right data is tracked. This adds a substantial level of flexibility, as there might be implementation-specific data that users cannot change, but may otherwise be updated which should be ignored for audit trailing.
We could also tweak the function slightly:
if (!auditProps.Any())
    auditProps = typeof(T).GetProperties();

So that if there is an object that doesn't have any audit attributes then, by default, choose all properties.

Now there was a comment in the question I want to look at for a moment:

While this is correct behavior, the omission is implicit and not obvious from the design.

This is an interesting note, because it speaks a bit to the problems we face when business logic requires the omission of something which is typically included. This is also one of those cases where we talk about comments adding value to code.
Generally, I am against comments unless they mean something. In the case they add meaning, then they add value and are worth including.
While it might seem ridiculous, the way I recommend checking the box off is as follows:
/** Documents are excluded from this method by design, users are
 *  mandated to first *Create* a `FinancialAgreement` then second
 *  *Update* that `FinancialAgreement` with the relevant documents.
 */

(I use the /** start & * on each line as a convention to create a comment block that explains a process or business logic concern and that should be included perpetually.)
Comments should never explain what the code does unless it's a beginner tutorial. (We should know what the code does from looking at it.) However, they can be used to explain why the code does what it does, especially when the meaning is not plainly obvious.

One last thing I don't love: lots of long lines. I would recommend putting together a defined responsibility to break those out into less-wide blocks. I generally set a limit of 100 or 120 characters per-line and then break them out into new-lines at reasonable locations (such as after a comma, or opening parenthesis, etc.). Some examples of this are in the code blocks I posted in this answer.
